# Safari 5.1 broke HTML native drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, drag-and-drop

Last night, I thought I'd do a quick project to demonstrate HTML5 capabilities and to try some things out. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get drag and drop to work in Safari, while it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. More precisely, it seems that drop event does not fire in Safari, when you try to drag an image inside the website into the drop area. At the same time it does fire when you drag and drop a file from desktop.

I'm not really sure, but I'm pretty certain that when I tried the same script at work (where I have Safari 5.0.2 etc), it fired the drop event (going to check it tomorrow to be sure) and gave me the FileReader-related errors that were expected. But when I just installed Safari 5.1 on my own PC, I only get dragover, enter and leave events (and drop too if the file was dragged into the browser).

I've been Googling for some time now and don't seem to find a single example of drag and drop that actually works in Safari 5.1. Even Safari's [dev-centre's sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/DragAndDrop.html) doesn't work, let alone [html5demo.com 1](http://html5demos.com/drag) and [html5demo.com 2](http://html5demos.com/drag-anything). This leads me to think whether the Safari has a bug, or maybe they have implemented something mandatory that isn't reflected in the dev-centre (last updated in 2009).

The script I'm trying to fix is at [my site](http://www.ut.ee/~vahurr/memebuilder) (sorry guys, no problem specific code to post, as it seems to be broken elsewhere too).

PS! I might have introduced some bugs into my own site while desperately trying to fix the drag and drop in Safari, but I'm too tired to fix them right now.

**UPDATE:** Just confirmed at work that the drop event does fire in Safari 5.0.2 on Mac OS X.

**UPDATE 2:** Also confirmed that everything works perfectly fine with Safari 5.0.6 on Win 7, the same computer that fails with 5.1

Comment: Confirming the errors OP describes, Safari 5.1 (7534.48.3). Worked fine in Chrome.

Comment: running 10.6.8 with Safari 5.1 (6534.50) works for me. 5.1 on Windows 7 does to. Is it a Lion issue?

Comment: Same for me: drag-drop fails on a fresh install of Safari 5.1 (7534.50) on Win7 x64, the same page worked fine in the previous version (and on Chrome/FF6/IE9). No extensions, empty cache.

Comment: Still broken in 5.1.7 (7534.57.2). Here's hoping it'll be fixed in Safari 6.

Answer (score 8):

Testing with Safari 5.1.7 Mac:

To see the `drop` event fire, you have to handle the `dragover` event and call `event.preventDefault()`.

Here's the (quite entertaining) discussion where I found the answer:

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html

I don't know if this really solves the question because the asker's site (at least as of today) does this.  It works fine on my machine (as do the HTML5 demo pages).  But this may help someone coming to this thread with this problem who doesn't know about this rather unintuitive implementation detail.

Comment: Calling `event.preventDefault()` worked for me in Safari 5.1.7 Win 7 x64.

Answer (score 5):

I am using Safari 5.1.5 (7534.55.3) on a Windows 7 PC which I just installed the other day, no previous installs of Safari and I cannot get any of the online HTML5 drag-n-drop demos to work.

I am working on a project with drag-n-drop and Modernizr tells me that I'm good to go with Safari (Modernizr.draganddrop == true), but when I actually drop the item the drop event does not fire.

I've added alert debugging and nothing.

My testing shows that Safari 5.1.5 (7534.55.3) on a Windows 7 PC drop event is broken.  All other drag events seem to work: dragstart, dragend, dragenter, dragleave, dragover.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify: Visited your site and found no errors. Opened the console, no error, and everything appeared to function as designed. Tried all provided examples with no error.

All examples work fine Safari Version 5.1 (7534.48.3). Sorry, mate – Maybe it's a setting you've changed?

Allow me to suggest a possibility:

Go to **`Safari`->`Empty Cache...`** Then **`Safari`->`Reset Safari...`** Try reloading the page.

Likely, there's something cached that's creating a conflict. <del>There seems to be nothing wrong with your script in the slightest.</del>

**Edit**

Some things to check...

Are any of your function names containing reserved words? I've done this, had it not throw any errors, but it simply wouldn't work.

I've had some weird issues with Safari not running methods written as `funcName = function(){}`. If you can pin down the method that isn't firing (I add a little function when I'm developing called DBG which I'll add below – basically, if a debug flag is set, you log to the console), you can try rewriting the function.

```
// Some sort of boolean flag.
var debug = true;

// This is kind of an obvious function, but can be expanded as you like.
// Little tricks to make life easier.
function DBG(str) {
  debug ? console.log(str) : return;
}
```

I still think ultimately this boils down to something caching wrong, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Yes, this would all be true if the problems occurred only in my script, but for some reason, a clean install of Safari doesn't like drag and drop (not even Safari documentation sample). I'll try reseting and cache emptying, but it seems to me that a certain combination of something causes this bug as I don't seem to be the only one (comment on my original post) experiencing it.

Comment: Which is strange – I'm running the exact same copy with no issue. Logically, if something runs as designed on some machines, using the same software, the problem shouldn't be the script or the software package, but some changeable aspect creating a conflict. Things that tend to change between users are: caches, settings, extensions... This brings up a good point – are you using any extensions in Safari? Check `Safari`->`Preferences...` and look under the `Extensions` tab. Since most extensions are JS, there may be a conflict.

Comment: It's a clean install (no previous versions of Safari either). Reseting and emptying cache had no effect either, tried installing 5.0.6 and everything worked perfectly, but on 5.1, no luck. It's probably gonna remain one of those mysterious bugs, that are impossible to track down by developers as they surface on rare occasions only under exact environmental circumstances.

Comment: In the spirit of being helpful, I'll agree that that is likely the case, and point you here: http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/safari/index.html There appear to be no shortage of weird bugs that intermittently appear. Just out of curiosity, you aren't running a nightly, right? It's the actual OSX update version?

Comment: Awarded you with points for your effort. Not using the nightly build, it's the official release. Hope it gets magically fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks mate, but this really has me puzzled, and it's going to become an issue for me too in the future, so trying to track down what seems to be occurring is purely selfish :) What I can't understand is why it works for me, and not for you using the same version. I'm assuming of course you have developer tools enabled as well. I'm just trying anything that's different.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issues, the drop event appeared to not be firing. Safari apparently expects the "dragover" event to also be bound. As soon as I also added that, it worked. So ... I'm sharing in case it's relevant.

*My first attempt:*

```
$(document).bind 
  drop: (e) ->
    // This never gets fired in safari (does work in chrome)
    console.log e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files
    false
```

*My "fix":*

```
$(document).bind 
  dragover: (e) ->
    console.log e
    false
  drop: (e) ->
    // This does get fired (in chrome and safari)
    console.log e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files
    false
```

Comment: I understand I've done something wrong to get that -1? But I'm not sure what ... Is that because my answer is seen as off topic? This was a real issue I encountered and my solution. This question was the one that came up in google when I searched my problem. I assume others will do the same, so I wanted to help those others. But is there some better way I should have handled that?

Comment: And reading further ... is my answer not the same concept (his is better, mine is worse) as John Starr Dewars?

Maybe the -1 is because his answer is better?

Comment: Probably some jQuery hater. Oh, and what is that yaml-esque syntax you got going on there? When in Rome, speak pure javascript. (Also, try not to worry about it. SO points are a bit "noisy" sometimes: it's swings and roundabouts.)