# Drag & Drop on Safari iOS: Won't drag, won't respond to drop on desktop/iPad

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, drag-and-drop

I am coding a webpage to be viewed on iPad. It uses Safaris/Webkits drag & drop. I have exactly copied Safari's example drag & drop code but it won't work.

**My Problem:** The ondrop event is never triggered when I run the webpage (HTML, CSS & Javascript) on Safari Desktop or on Safari on an iPad. On ipad I cannot even drag the elements (the microscope thingie appears & it won't drag when I hold & move my finger over the element). The drag does work on desktop though.

What's going wrong?

The small code example can be found at the very bottom of this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/DragAndDrop.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Drag-and-Drop</title>

  <script>
    <!--
    var dragitem = undefined;

    function setdragitem(item, evt) {
      dragitem = item;
      // alert('item: '+item);
      // item is an HTML DIV element.
      // evt is an event.

      // If the item should not be draggable, enable this next line.
      // evt.preventDefault();

      return true;
    }

    function cleardragitem() {
      dragitem = undefined;
      // alert('item: '+item);
    }

    function dodrag() {
      // alert('item: '+dragitem);
    }

    // This is required---used to tell WebKit that the drag should
    // be allowed.
    function handledragenter(elt, evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      return true;
    }

    function handledragover(elt, evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      return true;
    }


    function handledragleave(elt, evt) {

    }

    function handledrop(elt, evt) {
      // alert('drop');
      dragitem.style.display = "none";
      var newid = dragitem.id + '_dest';
      var dest = document.getElementById(newid);
      dest.innerHTML = dragitem.innerHTML;
    }


    // -->
  </script>

  <style>
    <!-- .wordbox {
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
      width: 50px;
      float: left;
      -webkit-user-drag: element;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
    }
    
    .spacer {
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .target {
      margin-top: 30px;
      padding: 30px;
      width: 70px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background: #c0c0ff;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      -webkit-user-drop: element;
    }
    
    .word {
      margin: 30px;
      min-height: 30px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      width: 50px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    -->
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <p>Drop words onto target area to put them in their places.</p>

  <div class='wordbox' id='this' ondragstart='setdragitem(this, event);' ondrag='dodrag();' ondragend='cleardragitem();'>This</div>
  <div class='wordbox' id='is' ondragstart='setdragitem(this, event);' ondrag='dodrag();' ondragend='cleardragitem();'>is</div>
  <div class='wordbox' id='a' ondragstart='setdragitem(this, event);' ondrag='dodrag();' ondragend='cleardragitem();'>a</div>
  <div class='wordbox' id='test' ondragstart='setdragitem(this, event);' ondrag='dodrag();' ondragend='cleardragitem();'>test</div>

  <div class='spacer'></div>
  <div class='target' ondragenter='handledragenter(this, event);' ondragover='handledragover(this, event);' ondragleave='handledragleave(this, event);' ondrop='handledrop(this, event);'>TARGET</div>

  <div class='words'>
    <div class='word' id='this_dest'></div>
    <div class='word' id='is_dest'></div>
    <div class='word' id='a_dest'></div>
    <div class='word' id='test_dest'></div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

**Here is the JSFiddle** (remember the drag & drop is Webkit so only for Safari-this webpage is for ipad only): https://jsfiddle.net/eyM3y/

Comment: i don't get your problem. I have just tested with Chrome (16.0.912.75) Safari (5.1.2 (7534.52.7)), and my iPad running iOS 5.0.1 and it works fine, handledrop is called. What is missing that I can't reproduce this?

Comment: @DanielKurka It doesn't work on safari version 5.1.2(7534.52.7). Nor does it work on my ipad. Are u on windows or macOS?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to accomplish. I get an alert every time I drag something, I just don't get anything in the spaces.

Comment: @nmagerko Are you using Safari? If so what OS are you on?

Comment: I am running on mac with lion

Comment: @DanielKurka: I'm on Windows 7 Professional & it doesn't work for me

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, too. I'm using Chrome 16.0.912.75

Comment: This seems to be an unknown bug in some cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002832/safari-5-1-broke-html-native-drag-and-drop Have had the same problem myself, never figure it out.

Answer (score 9):

Working alternative :

Firstly, use jquery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/ for drag and drop functionality

and then add this script https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch for playing it in Ipad or Iphone.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the top of the page you linked to in Apple's documentation? It says:

> Note: This technology is supported only on desktop versions of Safari. For iOS, use DOM Touch, described in Handling Events (part of Safari Web Content Guide) and Safari DOM Additions Reference.

[DOM Touch link](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511)

[Safari DOM Additions link](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Reference/SafariJSRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001482)

I believe you may want to listen for the touchmove and touchend events instead of on drag and on drop. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with one of my project but it can be resolved by following tutorial: http://popdevelop.com/2010/08/touching-the-web/ .  It works for me I hope you will like it.